# Hybris 5 trail, getting started

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I am getting started with Hybris. I am following the core trail on their wiki page. I am able to get the server up, but one thing that has been standing out from the start is this build error message:

```
updateMavenDependencies:
     [echo] C:\hybris\hybris\bin\platform\ext\core/web/webroot/WEB-INF/external-
dependencies.xml was not found!
```

...in C:\hybris\hybris\bin\platform\ext\core, there is no "web" directory (?)

the above issue of "web/webroot/WEB-INF/external-dependencies.xml was not found!" is not addressed yet....

below is answered by referenced thread -- thanks!

---

but there were no runtime issues until the "cuppy" demo where i am getting this spring IOC error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'openLigaDBTemplate' defined in class path resource [cuppy-ws-spring.xml]
: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.Be
anInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.client.c
ore.WebServiceTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.l
ang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(Ljava/lang/St
ring;)Ljava/lang/Class;
```

Thanks

Comment: yes, the ClassUtils.forName() error was caused by compiling with one version of a lib and running with another.  yes, it is fixed by Shreshtt Bhatt bellow  -- thanks!  but no -- it is not entirely a duplicate, because the first issue:  updateMavenDependencies:
     [echo] C:\hybris\hybris\bin\platform\ext\core/web/webroot/WEB-INF/external-
dependencies.xml was not found!
...in C:\hybris\hybris\bin\platform\ext\core, there is no "web" directory (?)        has not been addressed

Answer (score 7):

This is the compatibility issue with `Hybris 5.5.1`. Either you have to follow your trail with `Hybris 5.5.0` or replaced `sping-ws-1.5.9-all.jar` with `spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar`.

*Copy spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar and spring-ws-security-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar to cuppy/lib and delete the old jars.*

In Eclipse you should remove the old library from the build path and add the new ones.

Comment: thank you that fixes the problem !